# How to merge two checked out portions of a repository?

Tags: svn

I have checked out two different parts of a large repository a while ago, but now I need to commit a change that involves files in both parts. To avoid having to check everything out again, I'm trying to merge the two parts into a single working copy.

I tried checking out an empty root directory above the two subdirectories, then running svn update on both subdirectories. It sort of worked, but when I do svn status, it lists all subdirectories with question marks, and commit does nothing at all, even if I explicitly specify a changelist.

Answer (score 0):

It depends on how many changes you made. If you changed only files and not directory structure, then you can proceed by checking out from the repository root with no recursion, and then update only the needed paths to be fully recursive.

Supposing the you modified files under Component1/Trunk and Component2/Trunk directories in the repository, then the commands you need are -

```
svn checkout --depth empty repoUrl localRepo
svn update --depth immediates localRepo/Component1
svn update --depth immediates localRepo/Component2
svn update --depth infinity localRepo/Component1/Trunk
svn update --depth inifnity localRepo/Component2/Trunk
```

Once you have the repository in place, you can copy your modifications into the single checkout (only copying regular files, no subversion hidden directories). For this operation you may want to use a directory comparison tool such as meld or WinDiff - so that you copy only what you want to be committed.

Now you can commit to the repository via a single commit.

If either you modification affected directory tree structure or the repository evolved beyond simple file modification, you could have better look in performing a new checkout and applying your changes.

To avoid this problems in the future, you may want to look at "external" concepts in subversion to prepare a custom workspace that picks different parts of the repository.